# Remember @State variable after switching views

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm making an application for macOS with SwiftUI. I have a button that starts a download process asynchronously by calling `Task.init` and an async function. When the task starts, I set a `@State busy` variable to `true` so I can display a `ProgressView` while the download is happening. The problem is if I switch to a different view then back while it is downloading, the state gets reset although the task still runs. How can I make it so it remembers the state, or maybe check if the task is still running?

Here is a stripped down example:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct DownloadRow: View {
    let content: Content
    @State var busy = false
    
    var body: some View {
        if !busy {
            Button() {
                Task.init {
                    busy = true
                    await content.download()
                    busy = false
                }
            } label: {
                Label("Download")
            }
        } else {
            ProgressView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This isn't enough to demonstrate the issue. `@State` should not get reset like this. There's likely something you're doing that is creating a *new* `View`. Can you include a [mre]?

Comment: `@State` only persists state for the lifetime of a view - if the view is destroyed, its state is also destroyed. Creating an async `Task` inside the view does not extend the lifetime of the view - moreover, if the view is destroyed, so will the task created inside it be destroyed. If you want the task to outlive the view, you should store it on another object, whose lifetime isn't bound to the view's lifetime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the variable that tracks the download's progress into an `ObservableObject` class and make the progress variable `@Published`. Have the object that tracks your progress as an `@ObservedObject` in the view. By doing so, you decouple the progress tracker from the view's lifecycle. Make sure this view does not initialize the progress tracker, or a new object will be built when the view is built again.